# How to override and test a dependent method in Objective C or Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, macos, xctest

I am using XCTest for unit testing my Objective C code. I have to test method A() which in-turn calls B(). Is there a way I can override B() so that I can focus on testing A()?

An example given below.

```
- (void) A{
    int x = [self B];
    if(x == something)
    {
      // DoSomething
    }
    else
    {
      // DoSomething else
    }
}
```

My intention is to test A() for multiple responses/return values of B().

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mocked version of your object:

```
class MyClass {
    func a() -> String {
        return b("Hello")
    }

    func b(input: String) -> String {
        return string.capitalizedString
    }
}

class MockMyClass: MyClass {
    var mockedBValue: String = ""

    override func b(input: String) -> String {
        return mockedBValue
    }
}

// in your test:
let object = MockMyClass()
object.mockedBValue = "fdf"

let str = object.a()
//str now eqauls to "fdf"
```

Not sure what exactly is your implementation, but this should give you a hint.

You can also take a look at http://ocmock.org/

Answer (score 0):

*Dependency injection* is a technique that allows you to change implementation during unit testing. Google this term and learn to make your code more testable.